# Dialog Flow - Follow up Intents after Chips

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es, chatbot, android-chips

I am hoping that someone can assist me with the following question.

I am using Dialogflow for my chat and how do I build the responses based on what chip they click. I am drawing a blank. I can get the chips added but I am unsure where to build the responses.  Example would be: Are you an hourly or salaried employee. I need to set an answer for the Hourly chip and a different one for Salaried chip and I am unsure how to do that. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Each Intent you write represents an action by the user.
This includes selecting one of your suggestions, or typing them in themselves.

You then respond to the user based, in part, upon what they provide through the Intents.

So you should create an Intent representing they have selected "Hourly", and probably a different Intent representing they have selected "Salaried".